# Unable to move socket object into std::vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, c++11, stdvector

I have the following code :

```
try
{
    HAS::TCPServerSocket servSock(echoServPort);    // Socket descriptor for server
    std::vector<HAS::TCPSocket*> sockets(MAXCONN);
    for (;;)
    {
        try
        {
            if (socketCount < MAXCONN)
            {
                HAS::TCPSocket* sock(servSock.accept());
                sockets.push_back(sock);
                std::thread handler(handleTCPClient, std::ref(sockets[socketCount++]));
                handler.detach();
            }
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            cerr << "Unable to create thread" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to keep track of a limited number of connections `(MAXCONN=4)` and would like to keep track of opened sockets using a `std::vector`. Somehow, when I use the above code the `sock` variable gets properly set to the current socket as accepted by `servSock.accept()`. However, when I try to push the `sock` variable onto the `std::vector` I loose the sock object.

I have a feeling it has to do with properly specifying a copy and/or move constructor but I have defined both (and used breakpoints to see when the would be called) but they don't seem to get called at all.

Comment: std::vector<HAS::TCPSocket*> sockets(MAXCONN);
This should initialized your vector to have a max-size of 4 ? ... Thats not how vectors are supposed to work.

Comment: When `socketCount` has reached the maximal size, your program will just busy-loop. That looks like a terrible idea. Also, when will `socketCount` ever be *decremented*?

Comment: `std::vector<HAS::TCPSocket*> sockets(MAXCONN);` will initialize your vector to contain four null pointers, it won't do anything with a max size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

References to vector elements are invalidated when you say `push_back`. You can't use the code the way you have. You must first populate the entire vector and then never touch it again. Alternatively, use a container whose element references aren't invalidated by container mutations (`list` or `multiset` or `unordered_multiset` for general purpose, `deque` for insertion/deletion at the ends).

Or just pass a *copy* of the pointer to the thread?!

Comment: Thanks for the help ; std::list seems to work fine. Also I tried passing the pointer to the thread before - I think that would be the best way to go about it, however I couldn't get it to work. Will try again :)

Comment: @QNimbus: Your code has lots of other issues. I don't see why passing a copy wouldn't work, and that's by far the easiest and most appropriate solution.

Comment: @QNimbus: Consider following the advice in the last line, as it is better than the rest of the answer. You hold a pointer to a socket, just *copy* the pointer, there is no need to hold references to pointers for no particular reason (unless you need the `thread` to modify the pointer?).

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<HAS::TCPSocket*> sockets(MAXCONN);
...
sockets.push_back(sock);
std::thread handler(handleTCPClient, std::ref(sockets[socketCount++]));
```

That code looks funny. The vector will hold 4 null pointers, followed by the actual pointers that are added at the end with the `push_back()` calls. The threads will then get references to the first null pointers rather than the actual pointers you want.

You can do one of two things: my suggestion would be to use the default constructor of a vector and then call `reserve()` to guarantee that there won't be reallocations that invalidate the iterators with the `push_backs`. That would solve the problem. Alternatively, you can create the vector with the elements, but then don't call `push_back()` but rather use `operator[]` to modify the element at position `socketCount`.